# Trying chef cookbooks before uploading

Tags: vagrant, chef

We're using Vagrant & Chef to provision the staging VM for our app.

Once I have a working cookbook, I upload it to chef-server and Jenkins hook ensures the staging env gets updated.

However, it's not clear to me how to try out the cookbook before I upload it. I can't use chef-solo because we're using environments.

Should I run a chef-server locally in a VM and upload it there?
Or should I fix the cookbook versions in the run-lists and upload a new version (so that staging still uses the old one and does not break if the new version is wrong)?

How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Test Kitchen](http://kitchen.ci) with the chef-zero provisioner.

There are several examples that use this:

- https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-splunk
- https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-vault
- https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/rsyslog

To enable zero as the provisioner, put this in a .kitchen.yml

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
```

You'll need to create mock environments, which you should create as JSON files in `test/integration/environments`.

Additional documentation about Test Kitchen is maintained by [Chef Docs](https://docs.chef.io/kitchen.html)